# Using 'newUUID()' aws iot function in AWS SiteWise service that returns a random 16-byte UUID to be stored as a partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot-sitewise

I am trying to use the ['newUUID()' aws iot function](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-iot-docs/blob/master/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.md#newuuid) in the AWS SiteWise service (as part of an alarm action) that returns a random 16-byte UUID to be stored as a partition key for a DynamoDb tables partition key column.

With reference to the attached screenshot, in the 'PartitionKeyValue' trying to
use the value returned by newUUID() function that will be passed to the DynamoDb as part of the action trigger.[image: Action_settings_dialog_box]

Although this gives an error as follows:
"Invalid Request exception: Failed to parse expression due to: Invalid expression. Unrecognized function: newUUID".

I do understand the error, but not sure how can I solve this and use a random UUID generator. Kindly note that I do not want to use a timestamp, because there could be eventualities where multiple events get triggered at the same time and hence the same timestamp.

Any ideas that how can I use this function, or any other information that helps me achieve the above-mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The docs you refer to say that function is all lowercase `newuuid()`.

Perhaps that will work, but I believe that function is only available in [IoT Core SQL Statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-reference.html).  I think with event notifications, you only have these [expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotevents/latest/developerguide/iotevents-expressions.html) to work with, which is not much.  Essentially, you need to get what you need from the alarm event itself.

You may need the alarm event to invoke Lambda, rather than directly write to DynamoDB.  Your Lambda function can create a UUID and write the alarm record to DynamoDB using the SDKs.